# AngularJS: Assigning a Watcher to Inputs Created in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular.  I'm modifying an existing administration page which contains a list of users, and the ability to toggle on/off roles for each user. I'm trying to add watchers to each role so I can save the changes.

I'm using directive for Users (for multiple User objects), and getting the json (an array of user objects, with an array of roles) that populates it from an ajax call:

```
[
    {
        "Email": "foo@bar.com",
        "Roles": [
            {
                "Role": "admin",
                "HasRole": true
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

In my User directive html template/snippet called user_card.html, I'm looping over the roles to output the radio buttons:

```
<div class="permission" ng-repeat="role in user.Roles">
    <p>{{role.Role}} -- {{role.HasRole}}</p>

    <input type="radio" id="{{user.Email}}_{{role.Role}}_false" ng-attr-name="{{user.Email}}_{{role.Role}}" ng-value="false" ng-model="role.HasRole" />
    <label for="{{user.Email}}_{{role.Role}}_false"><span></span>Off</label>

    <input type="radio" id="{{user.Email}}_{{role.Role}}_true" ng-attr-name="{{user.Email}}_{{role.Role}}" ng-value="true" ng-model="role.HasRole" />
    <label for="{{user.Email}}_{{role.Role}}_true"><span></span>On</label>
</div>
```

I can see that the ng-model is working properly because on the code snippet above, I can see the {{role.HasRole}} changing between true and false.

What I'm trying to do is add a watcher so that when a role is changed, a watcher will be triggered. I have tried this code (and several over variations) to no avail.  Here's the JavaScript behind the User directive (user_card_directive.js):

```
scope.user.Roles.forEach(function (role) {
    console.log(role);

    scope.$watch('role.HasRole', function (newValue, oldValue) {

        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            console.log(newValue);
        };
    });
});
```

I'm guessing I'm doing something incorrect in this user_card_directive.js to add a watcher on the roles.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: Why do you need a watch ? For any change in scope values angular triggers its digest cycle. I guess a simple ng-click/ng-change would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through `users` and adding watcher to each `role`, you can do a deep watch on an array object like below :

```
$scope.$watch('user.Roles.HasRole', function (newValue) {
 //Whatever you want to do after watch triggered 
 ...

}, true);
```

Comment: Hey suzo, thanks for your response!  I appreciate it.  I see what you mean, but I still couldn't get the watch to work.  I was able to get it with ng-change; do you have any concerns with simply using ng-change?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using the `ng-change` directive. which evaluates the given expression when the user changes the input.

```
<div class="permission" ng-repeat="role in user.Roles">
    <p>{{role.Role}} -- {{role.HasRole}}</p>

    <input type="radio"  ng-change="roleUpdated(role)" id="{{user.Email}}_{{role.Role}}_false" ng-attr-name="{{user.Email}}_{{role.Role}}" ng-value="false" ng-model="role.HasRole" />
    <label for="{{user.Email}}_{{role.Role}}_false"><span></span>Off</label>

    <input type="radio" ng-change="roleUpdated(role)" id="{{user.Email}}_{{role.Role}}_true" ng-attr-name="{{user.Email}}_{{role.Role}}" ng-value="true" ng-model="role.HasRole" />
    <label for="{{user.Email}}_{{role.Role}}_true"><span></span>On</label>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.roleUpdated= function(newRole) {
     console.log(newRole);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel!  I got this working with ng-change.  I found that since my code is within a Directive, I had to create a method in the user_card_directive.js instead of the Controller. Now I should be able to do what I need to :)